# How to get PHP time tomorrow 6pm CST?

Tags: php, time, timestamp

I need get a timestamp in PHP for the next day 6pm CST

```
$tomorrow = mktime(18, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+1, date("y"));
echo "Tomorrow is ".date("Y-m-d H:m:s ", $tomorrow);
```

I was unable to set the minutes part for the above code, it is always returning 11 in the minutes part.

```
Tomorrow is 2009-11-06 18:11:00
```

Comment: Apache Version : 2.2.11  
PHP Version : 5.2.11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your date format `Y-m-d H:m:s` you are showing the month twice `m`.  use `i` for minutes with leading zeros: `Y-m-d H:i:s` ([PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

Answer (score 8):

A simpler version is to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
echo "Tomorrow is ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s ", strtotime("Tomorrow 6pm"));
```

including correcting the minutes (from m to i). Output:

```
Tomorrow is 2009-11-06 18:00:00
```